# How to generate serial number based on condition based in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have one table name called "ABC".

**"ABC" Table format :**

```
Operation   Status    value
----------------------------
OP10          1        100
OP10          1        200
OP10          2        300
OP20          1        400
OP20          3        500
OP30          1        100
OP30          2        200
```

I need to generate serial number for based on Operation.

E.g: Expected Output

```
SNo   Operation   Status    Value
-----------------------------------
1      OP10          1        100
1      OP10          1        200
1      OP10          2        300
2      OP20          1        400
2      OP20          3        500
3      OP30          1        100
3      OP30          2        200
```

How to get the result as above formatted output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DENSE_RANK()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx)

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Operation) SNo,
       Operation, Status, Value
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Value
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Demo here:**

## Rextester